# Should I use API every time I need data or Store all data in database and access whenever needed

Tags: php, database, api, wikipedia

This is a design question.

I am creating a web application, where I have a page where I would need to display different sections but not all of a wikipedia page.

Now let's consider this scenario,

I need to display 5 sections of a wikipedia page on my website.

**How do I do it?**

1. I would make 5 calls for different sections as below

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=xml&action=parse&page=xyz&prop=text&section=2

2. I would have database with all 5 sections stored already, just make single call and get all sections. (It would need a lot of db space to keep data stored in my db).
3. Any other suggestions you might have????

I am looking for a solution which can pull data with high speed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as speed is concern go for local database storing but if memory is concern then go for API call. As per my opinion, I think you should go for local database...